# Processes fail to exit() when job count exceeds n

Tags: python, process, queue, multiprocessing, exit

I'm running `Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`.

I spawn 4 processes, give them 2 queues - for tasks and results, and join the task queue at the end. And when the task count reaches a certain amount - `njobs = 10000` for example - some of the children and the main process won't exit, even though all tasks are done.

Why is this?

The code to illustrate this

```
def worker(job_queue, result_queue):
    import Queue

    while True:
        try:
            j = job_queue.get(False)
        except Queue.Empty:
            exit('done')
        else:
            result_queue.put_nowait(j)
            job_queue.task_done()

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue, Process, cpu_count

    job_queue = JoinableQueue()
    result_queue = JoinableQueue()

    njobs = 10000
    for i in xrange(njobs):
        job_queue.put(i)

    cpus = cpu_count()
    for i in xrange(cpus):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(job_queue, result_queue))
        p.start()

    job_queue.join()
    print("DONE")
```

And the longer the task, the lower number of tasks required for someone (or all) processes to hang. Originally, I'm doing sequence matching with this. And it usually leaves 3 processes hanging when queue is about 500.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using a [Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)? It does pretty much exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: In my original case data arrives continuously. Otherwise yes, I'd use a pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, having more than 6570 items in a queue might cause a deadlock (more information in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026050/subprocess-completes-but-still-doesnt-terminate-causing-deadlock)). What you can do is empty `result_queue` at the end of the main execution:

```
while not result_queue.empty():
    result_queue.get(False)
    result_queue.task_done()
print "Done"
```

Note that you don't have to call `exit` in the worker function, `return` is enough:

```
except Queue.Empty:
    print "done"
    return
```

You might also consider using a [Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def task(arg):
    """Called by the workers"""
    return arg

def callback(arg):
    """Called by the main process"""
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    pool = Pool()
    njobs = 10000
    print "Enqueuing tasks"
    for i in xrange(njobs):
        pool.apply_async(task, (i,), callback=callback)
    print "Closing the pool"
    pool.close()
    print "Joining the pool"
    pool.join()
    print "Done"
```

Comment: Yes, emptying the result queue helped. So every queue used should be empty? And thanks for the pool variant.

Comment: Also, any idea why it works without emptying result queue, when task number is lower?

Comment: Apparently, having more than 6570 items in a queue might cause a deadlock. More information in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026050/subprocess-completes-but-still-doesnt-terminate-causing-deadlock).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Understood the issue now completely, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation limit with pipes or sockets well described in [Issue 8426: multiprocessing.Queue fails to get() very large objects](http://bugs.python.org/issue8426). Note it also applies to a lot of small objects.

**Solution**

Either

- make sure to consume the result queue concurrently fast enough
- from child processes, call `Queue.cancel_join_thread()`

**Documentation**

> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait
>   before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the
>   “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe. (The child process can call
>   the cancel_join_thread() method of the queue to avoid this behaviour.)
>
> This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that
>   all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed
>   before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure that
>   processes which have put items on the queue will terminate. Remember
>   also that non-daemonic processes will be joined automatically.

— [Multiprocessing - Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming)